# Question 4A.9 of Finite group theory by Martin Isaacs

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G = NA$, where $N \lhd G$ and $ A \subseteq G$, and let $M$ be the final term in the series

$$N \supset [N, A] \supset [N, A, A] \supset [N, A, A, A] \supset \cdots \supset M,$$

where $[A, B, C] =[ [A, B], C]$. Show that $A \lhd\lhd G$ iff $M \subseteq A$. Note that $A \lhd\lhd G$ means $A$ is subnormal in $G.$

### $\Rightarrow$ part:

Suppose $A \lhd\lhd G$, then there exists a chain of subgroup $A_1$, $A_2$ $ \cdots$ such that $ A \lhd A_1 \lhd A_2 \lhd \cdots \lhd A_n \lhd G$.

Consider $ G \supset [G, A_n] \supset \cdots \supset [G, A_n, \cdots A_2] \supset [G, \cdots A_2, A_1] \supset [G, \cdots A_2, A_1, A]$. Easy induction shows that $[G, A_n, \cdots A_i] \subseteq A_i$ and $[G, A_n, \cdots A_i] \supset [N, A, A, \cdots, A]$ there are $n-i+1$ A's in the second expression. Therefore $A \supset M$.

### $\Leftarrow$ part:

Suppose $M \subseteq A$. I have a strong intuition that $A = AM \lhd \cdots \lhd A[N, A, A] \lhd A[N, A] \lhd AN = G$. But I don't know how to show my conjecture formally.

Please help.

Comment: There is a general result that, for subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a group $G$, the subgroup $[H,K]$ is normalized by $H$ and $K$. You can use that to show that $[N,A, \ldots (i+1)\ldots ,A]A$ is normal in $[N,A, \ldots (i)\ldots ,A]A$

Comment: @Derek Yes. A core observation for this question indeed. I always think in a more complicate way.